# Need help understanding how VSCode processes environment variables

Tags: windows, visual-studio-code, cmder

I have always had issues understanding how VSCode process environment variables on Windows. Currently, I am trying to integrate Cmder with VSCode as my shell using the json below that I found on Github:

```
"terminal.integrated.shell.windows": "cmd.exe",

  "terminal.integrated.env.windows": {
  "CMDER_ROOT": "[cmder_root]"
  },
  "terminal.integrated.shellArgs.windows": [
    "/k",
    "%CMDER_ROOT%\\vendor\\bin\\vscode_init.cmd"
  ],
```

I was trying to replace `"[cmder_root]"` with a variable defined in the OS but cannot get VSCode to recognize it. When I create the variable as a System variable, if I run `set` at the cmd.exe prompt of the integrated terminal, it shows the new variable name and the value I set it to but VSCode won't use it because it will not start Cmder when I open a terminal.

If I define the variable in the OS as User variable, running `set` inside the integrated terminal no longer displays that variable with the value I set it to. It displays it as `CMDER_ROOT=%CMDER_ROOT%`.

I finally got Cmder to work by hard coding the path in the settings.json file but it just made me want to find out what I am doing wrong.

Comment: Try ${env:CMDER_ROOT}  reference: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/variables-reference

Comment: @xsoftie that did the trick...thanks. Still don't understand how VSCode process the User and System variables though.

Comment: I'm assuming you mean Windows user and system environment variables? We could follow the path from the PEB up to where they are used via the syntax I posted but I'm not sure that is very interesting.